# Submit form confirm alert sweet_alert.min.js

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I am using the library js / sweet_alert.min.js, I need that when confirming the alert the form is sent and I can not do `this.form.submit();` is not working

**JS:**

```
$('#sweet_warning').on('click', function() {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');        
    swal({
        title: "¿Está seguro que desea cargar esta mesa?",
        text: "",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        confirmButtonColor: "#FF7043",
        confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"            
    },
    function(isConfirm){        
         form.submit();     
    }
    );
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
  <button type="button" name="submiti" id="sweet_warning" class="btn bg-warning">
    Ingresar <i class="icon-circle-right2 position-right"></i>
  </button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget previous version and use this snippet in latest version `version 2`:

```js
$('#sweet_warning').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  swal({
    title: "¿Está seguro que desea cargar esta mesa?",
    text: "",
    buttons: {
      text: "Aceptar!",
      cancel: "Cancelar!"
    }
  }).then(
    function(isConfirm) {
      alert(isConfirm)
      if(isConfirm){
        $('#your_form').submit();
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="" id="your_form">
  <button type="button" name="submiti" id="sweet_warning" class="btn bg-warning">
    Ingresar <i class="icon-circle-right2 position-right"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @FernandoRossi you did not add `e` in your arguments handler. i've edited

Comment: When making these changes the form is sent without displaying the confirmation alert, it is ignored

Comment: @FernandoRossi it seems in last version of sweatalert `callback` is deprecated. which version do you have?

Comment: It does not say what version it is, but I think it's the first not the second https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gbDQD6M5voOw1FnkkCX6rkBksZ3uJpMI

Comment: @FernandoRossi I dont understand which version is it but I changed my code to newest version using `then()`. make all changes in your code and check it out. I think you are using newest version.

Comment: then not working I'm going to download version 2 to see if it works

Comment: @FernandoRossi I've added snippet with `version 2`, it's working